# Image Control asynchronous

Tags: c#, silverlight, asynchronous, windows-phone-7, controls

I have an image control that I want it to load the image asynchronously over the network. I see some sample code in the network saying something like:

`<Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="118" Margin="2,8,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="167" x:Name="ImageThumbnail" Source="{Binding SummaryImageLink, IsAsync=True}" />`

However, in **Windows Phone 7**, I cannot find anything like that. Does anybody know a way to do that without I have to code a lot myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you are going to have to write, or include, more code yourself to do this properly. I have a similar solution with the goal to cache images after the first download. The image cache class is accessed via a IValueConverter, so once you have included the appropriate code, you only have to add a decorator on the Image object:

```
<Image Source="{Binding ElementName=ImageSource, Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource imageCacheConverter}}" Width="200" />
```

Full details here and source code here: http://www.ben.geek.nz/2010/07/one-time-cached-images-in-windows-phone-7/

Answer (score 1):

David Anson's work with LowProfileImageLoader may be of interest to you.

[Keep a low profile [LowProfileImageLoader helps the Windows Phone 7 UI thread stay responsive by loading images in the background] - Delay's Blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/delay/keep-a-low-profile-lowprofileimageloader-helps-the-windows-phone-7-ui-thread-stay-responsive-by-loading-images-in-the-background)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can asynchronously download the picture (for ex. with a BackgroundWorker) and assign it as source for your image control only when the download has completed.

Comment: That is a possible solution but I have to write some more code