# How to cache downloaded images

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am using below code direct bind all the data into the list including images

```
void ListPostComingsoon_Completed(object sender, ListPostComingsoonCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        ComingSoonList.ItemsSource = e.Result;

    }
```

And the List<> structure is something like below

```
select new post
              {

                  postid = (int)r.postid,
                  userid = (int)r.userid,
                  NofLikeString = r.NofLike.ToString() + " Likes",
                  title = r.title,
                  startdate = r.startdate.ToString(),
                  enddate = r.enddate.ToString(),
                  image =   "http://localhost:6848/photo/" + r.image

              }).ToList();
```

How can i achieve image caching(the image show separately once it's downloaded)?

Comment: take a look on this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244662/image-control-asynchronous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got a solution for you. It is [JetImageLoader](https://github.com/artem-zinnatullin/jet-image-loader), I created it for application, where we need to load, cache and show big amount of logos, icons and so on.

It can be used as binding converter, so *you should not even change your code! Just update your XAMLs!*

Please, check out [samples in repository](https://github.com/artem-zinnatullin/jet-image-loader), you'll love it ;)

**Features:**

- Caching on disk
- Caching in memory
- Fully asynchronous
- Available as binding converter or programmatically from your code
- Fully open source, fork and improve it!

Here is the example:

```
<Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl, Converter={StaticResource MyAppJetImageLoaderConverter}}"/>
```

P.S. I am sorry, that I copying my answer from another questions, but image caching on windows phone is huge problem and I want to share my solution, so everybody can use it and improve for developers community